# Display Wordcount on Page Load

Tags: jquery, load, focus

This might sound like a noob question but I have a problem with a simple function that **should display a wordcounter on page load**. At the moment I created one that displays the result on focus but I cannot get it running right off.

There is a textarea that gets its content from database, so that when the page is loaded, the textarea is already filled.

This is the code right now:

```
var oTextArea = $('#textarea');
var oDisplay = $('#display');

  oTextArea.on('focus', function()
    {
      var words = this.value.match(/\S+/g).length;
      if (words > 1)
      {
          oDisplay.text(words);
      }
    });
```

https://jsfiddle.net/fischkopp/2vrLLtfr/

I tried numerous things beside that "solution" but I did´t find one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like that?

```
var oTextArea = $('#textarea');
var oDisplay = $('#display');

//onload
$(function() {
    countWords(); //call this function after your textarea has been filled
    oTextArea.on('focus', countWords);
    oTextArea.on('blur', countWords);
});

function countWords() {
  var words =  $('#textarea').val().match(/\S+/g).length;
  if (words > 1) {
    oDisplay.text(words);
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I forgot to mention that it should update, if the text is edited but I just had to add a little 'keyup' tp your code and now it works fine!

Answer (score 0):

You are mixing jQuery and pure JS. use the following to display on load:

```
var oTextArea = $('#textarea');
var oDisplay = $('#display');

oDisplay.text(oTextArea.val().match(/\S+/g).length);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for ypu help!

Answer (score 0):

**you can use split() to split string by space's and store into an array and just getting the length of an array !**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Bootstrap Theme Simply Me</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('#textarea').on('focus', function () {//Delete this line to get length on document ready
                var arr = $('#textarea').text().split(" ");
                $('#display').text(arr.length);
            });
        });//Delete
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <textarea id="textarea" rows="20" placeholder="Enter Text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</textarea>
            <div id="display">
                Will be displayed here on focus
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```